# Having an issue unchecking box in JQuery 1.9

Tags: jquery

I am putting together a list of skills based on point values and when I go over the point value, I want to flash a message and uncheck the box they've selected.  I've been trying to use .prop("checked", false), but I can't seem to make it work without specifically stating which checkbox to uncheck.  I'd like to use the one they just checked.

I've tried both with and without checkboxradio(refresh)

http://jsfiddle.net/mattcushing/K5szE/7/

```
function calculateTotal() {
    var curr = starting;
    var checked = $("input:checked").each(function (item) {
        curr -= +($(this).prev(".amt").text());
    });
    if(curr < 0){
    alert("Please change your options, you can't have a negative value");
    $(this).prop("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh");
    }
    else{
    $("#remaining").text(curr);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/K5szE/8/)

You are using `this` keyword out of context. Try returning the value from `calculateTotal()`  and use `this` keyword in the event handler.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
        changeCostRogue();
        changeCostWarrior();
        changeCostMage();
        var curr = calculateTotal();
        if(curr < 0){
        alert("dude, no negatives!");
        $(this).prop("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh");
        }
        else{
        $("#remaining").text(curr);
        }
    });

function calculateTotal() {
        var curr = starting;
        var checked = $("input:checked").each(function (item) {
            curr -= +($(this).prev(".amt").text());
        });
        return curr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to send `this` to your calculateTotal function

```
calculateTotal(this);
```

and change your function's signature like

```
function calculateTotal(this) {
```